# Eclipse launch configuration: resolve active profiles in project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have several `.launch` files for Eclipse (I'm using Eclipse Oxygen), here is an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.m2e.Maven2LaunchConfigurationType">
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_DEBUG_OUTPUT" value="false" />
    <stringAttribute key="M2_GOALS" value="clean com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:deploy" />
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_NON_RECURSIVE" value="false" />
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_OFFLINE" value="false" />
    <stringAttribute key="M2_PROFILES" value="" />
    <listAttribute key="M2_PROPERTIES" />
    <stringAttribute key="M2_RUNTIME" value="EMBEDDED" />
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_SKIP_TESTS" value="true" />
    <intAttribute key="M2_THREADS" value="1" />
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_UPDATE_SNAPSHOTS" value="false" />
    <stringAttribute key="M2_USER_SETTINGS" value="" />
    <booleanAttribute key="M2_WORKSPACE_RESOLUTION" value="false" />
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc}" />
</launchConfiguration>
```

Note that I'm using `${project_loc}` variable in order to make it usable for any project.

I'm using this kind of files because I can share those with my team. Also the most used Maven Build configurations are ready to go w/o configuring every time a new launch profile.

The problem I'm facing is related to the profile value

```
<stringAttribute key="M2_PROFILES" value="" />
```

With the `CTRL+ALT+P` shortcut on a project, I can select the proper profile to load (`Select Maven Profiles...` function). I'm using different profile to discern the environment for the deploy (development, stage o production).

I'm trying to "inject" the profile I enabled for the project into the generic launch profile configuration, something like the `${project_loc}` variable but related to the current Maven profile.

If this cannot be made I need to create a launch profile for each environment, which means 3 files per every goal to launch.

Is there a way to use/create an Eclipse variable that can be resolved with the Maven profile I activated on the project?

Something like

```
<stringAttribute key="M2_PROFILES" value="${maven.profile.id}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an Eclipse plugin (or contribute to Eclipse m2e project) in order to define a variable using the [dedicated extension-point](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_core_variables_dynamicVariables.html&resultof=%22%76%61%72%69%61%62%6C%65%73%22%20%22%76%61%72%69%61%62%6C%22%20%22%65%78%74%65%6E%73%69%6F%6E%22%20%22%65%78%74%65%6E%73%22%20).